# Storing duplicate data as a column in Postgres?

Tags: postgresql

In some database project, I have a `users` table which somehow has a computed value `avg_service_rating`. And there is another table called `services` with all the services associated to the user and the ratings for that service. Is there a computationally-lite way which I can maintain the `avg_service_rating` rating without updating it every time an INSERT is done on the services table? Perhaps like a generate column but with a function call instead? Any direct advice or link to resources will be greatly appreciated as well!

```
CREATE TABLE users (
    username VARCHAR PRIMARY KEY,
    avg_service_ratings NUMERIC -- is it possible to store some function call for this column?,
    ...
);

CREATE TABLE service (
    username VARCHAR NOT NULL REFERENCE users (username);
    service_date DATE NOT NULL,
    rating INTEGER,
    PRIMARY KEY (username, service_date),
);
```

Comment: Have you considered using a view?

Comment: I have thought of using a view but I do not know how to justify the change from getting rid of the column to my group mates. So I figured there should be some way to store function call as a column or generate it dynamically. Furthermore, I think almost everyone wants to avoid a refactor on the current queries we have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the values should be consistent, a generated column won't fit the bill, since it is only recomputed if the row itself is modified.

I see two solutions:

1. have a trigger on the `services` table that updates the `users` table whenever a rating is added or modified. That slows down data modifications, but not your queries.
2. Turn `users` into a view. The original `users` table would be renamed, and it loses the `avg_service_rating` column, which is computed on the fly by the view.

   To make the illusion perfect, create an `INSTEAD OF INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE` trigger on the view that modifies the underlying table. Then your application does not need to be changed.

   With this solution you pay a certain price both on `SELECT` and on data modifications, but the latter price will be lower, since you don't have to modify two tables (and `users` might receive fewer modifications than `services`). An added advantage is that you avoid data duplication.

Answer (score 1):

A [generated column](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-generated-columns.html) would only be useful if the source data is in the same table row.

Otherwise your options are a view (where you could call a function or calculate the value via a subquery), or an `AFTER UPDATE OR INSERT` trigger on the `service` table, which updates `users.avg_service_ratings`. With a trigger, if you get a lot of  updates on the `service` table you'd need to consider possible concurrency issues, but it would mean the figure doesn't need to be calculated every time a row in the `users` table is accessed.